# Java - вопрос про ресурсоемкость параметров-объектов в методах

Tags: java, производительность

Как известно, объекты передаваемые в функциях являются ссылками, поэтому напрашивается такой вопрос: примерно одинаково затратно будут первые два способа либо второй практически равноценен созданию новых объектов, что, как я понимаю,  безумно затратно (третий способ)?

Первый:

```
class A {

  ArrayList < Point > list;

  public A() {
   list = new ArrayList < Point > ();
   //представим, что тут лист заполняется сотней новых объектов
   update();
  }

  void update() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    list.get(i).set(i, i); // 
   }
  }
 }
```

Второй:

```
class B {

  ArrayList < Point > list;

  public B() {
   list = new ArrayList < Point > ();
   //представим, что тут лист заполняется сотней новых объектов
   update(list);
  }

  void update(ArrayList < Point > p) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    p.get(i).set(i, i); // 
   }
  }
 }
```

Третий:

```
class С {

 ArrayList <Point> list;

 public С() {
  list = new ArrayList <Point> ();
  //представим, что тут лист заполняется сотней новых объектов
  list = update();
 }

 ArrayList <Point> update() {
  ArrayList <Point> pp = new ArrayList <Point> ();
  pp.addAll(list);
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   pp.get(i).set(i, i); // 
  }
  return pp;
 }
}
```

Смело использовать второй способ или все же продолжить проводить операции только с полями классов, если возможно?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Первые два способа по стоимости практически одинаковы. Передача ссылочного типа есть не что иное, как передача ссылки (то есть, указателя, если вы знакомы с С или C++). Размер ссылки равен размеру одного регистра процессора на популярных платформах (то есть, практически бесплатно). Второй способ, однако, лучше тем, что у него меньшая *связность*: ваш метод `update` может использоваться не только с полем `A.list`, а и с любым другим объектом подходящего типа.

Третий способ, разумеется, дороже (особенно для больших списков): у вас дополнительные расходы на копирование списка (не *ссылки* на список, а *данных* списка!).

Comment: занудное уточнение: при некоторых обстоятельствах (64 бит, нужные включенные опции) размер ссылки в джаве может быть даже [меньше](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/CompressedOops)

Comment: @etki: Круто, не знал, спасибо!